# postgresql option to both insert new row despite "conflict" or update existing row

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

If I have a postgresql table like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.time_series
      (id serial PRIMARY KEY,
      variable_id integer NOT NULL,
      datetime timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
      value real NOT NULL,
      edit_datetime timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now())
```

Im not having any constrains here except the primary key. For now..

And i want to have the option to either `UPDATE` OR `INSERT` new data where it is essentially the same variable for the same datetime.  So that I can choose to either overwrite or just have a new version.. How do a proceede to do that?

Without constrains and if I want to `INSERT` some data; I do some `WHERE NOT EXISTS` where i make sure that the new data does not correlate with a row that has the same variable_id, datetime, and value. And it works just fine.

Now if the case is that I want to `UPDATE` if it exists and else `INSERT` I make a `CONSTRAINT` like:

```
ALTER TABLE public.time_series
    ADD CONSTRAINT unique_comp UNIQUE (variable_id, datetime)
```

And updates the row if there is a conflict and `INSERT` if there is non.

And it works just fine..

But, again, what if I for some variables wants pervious "versions" where i can see them based on edit_datetime and want some other variables to be overwritten with the new data? Currently one way rules out the other one.

BR

Comment: What is the purpose of `edit_datetime`, on which scenario this column is added/edited?

Comment: @ThangLeQuoc it will just show when the data was submitted to the database.
For some variables I need to see previous versions of the data. and for some variables it would be a waste of time and space.  Some times i also need to check when a event happened hence when it was incjected to the db.
So it will be updated only when the row was inserted or updated with new data i the value column.

Comment: Have you checked [upsert](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/write-data/upsert/#upsert-functionality)?